# C - char array longer after sending over network

Tags: c, char, arrays

I want to send a char array consisting of only numeric values over the network, but after I receive it, the number is longer than before with some extra characters.

For example I send:

```
579858766387684363076422
strlen size 24
char[] prints correct here
```

But what I receive is:

```
Got message: 579858766387684363076422 with length 27 
strlen size 27
(also there appear special characters in console at the end)
```

My send code:

```
char *aArray = toCharArray(&alpha);

// write to client
n = write(newsockfd, aArray, strlen(aArray));
if (n < 0) 
    error("ERROR writing to socket");
```

My receive code:

```
n = read(sockfd, buffer, 512);
if (n < 0) 
    error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("Got message: %s with length %d\n", buffer, n);
```

Does anyone know whats going on? I am a total beginner in C by the way.

This is how I generate my char array from an array of numbers if anyone wants to take a look:

```
char * toCharArray(largenum *num) {
    char *output = malloc(sizeof(char) * num->size);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < num->size; ++i)
    {
        output[i] = num->digits[i] + '0';
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Could you some place for the terminating character `\0` ? `char *output = malloc(sizeof(char) * (num->size+1));` and `output[num->size]='\0'`

Comment: Hey @francis: This gives me server.c:169:23: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default] output[num->size] = "\0";
How can I fix this? :)

Comment: @luuksen: Read carefully. Single quotes, not double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `strlen()` on a buffer that is not null-terminated, so it's running off the end into garbage data. I don't see what part of your code prints "strlen size 24", but I presume it's either acquiring the length some other way, or the heap just happens to have a null at the end of the string at that point.

Make your `toCharArray` function properly null-terminate the string it creates.